# Select timestamps for these values SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello currently I have a working script below. I am using oracles 10

```
SELECT z.ID as "ID_One",
MAX(r.value) as "Max", 
round(MAX(r.value)/80000,2) as "ROUND" 
FROM Table1 r, Table2 z 
WHERE r.timestamp > ((SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 * 60 * 60) - 80000 
AND r.id=21 
AND r.animalid IN ('7','98','3','3') 
AND r.id = z.id group by r.id, r.animalid,z.id;
```

It produces a table like this

```
ID_ONE MAX ROUND
1      500 232   
2      232 32  
3      23  .21
4      34  .321
```

I want to select a row call timestamp from table r. However when I add " r.timestamp " in to my query it produces 500 rows of data instead of 4. It looks like it is producing the the highest number for each timestamp instead. How would I produce a table that looks like this ? fyi timestamp column is in unix time. I can do the conversion myself. I just need to know how to get out these rows.

```
ID_ONE MAX ROUND   TIMESTAMP
1      500 232     DEC 21,2021 10:00
2      232 32      DEC 21,2021 23:12 
3      23  .21     DEC 31,2021 2:12
4      34  .321    DEC 31,2021 23:12
```

Comment: How do you use Oracle with SQLite?

Comment: If there are multiple timestamps for each ID, which one do you want - the highest, or the one that corresponds to the highest `r.value`?

Comment: Basically I want the highest r.value for a set timestamp. not the highest timestamp

Answer (score 0):

If you want other values from the row you're getting the `MAX` from, you can use analytic functions in a subquery instead of aggregates. There are various ways; this one ranks each row in the original tables such that the row with the highest `value` for each `id` is ranked first, and the outer query then only returns those.

```
SELECT id AS "ID_One",
  value as "Max",
  ROUND(value/80000,2) AS "ROUND",
  timestamp,
  TO_CHAR(DATE '1970-01-01' + (timestamp / (24 * 60 * 60)),
    'MON DD,YYYY HH24:MI') AS timestamp_date
FROM (
  SELECT z.id,
    r.value,
    r.timestamp,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY r.id, r.animalid ORDER BY r.value DESC) AS rnk
  FROM Table1 r, Table2 z 
  WHERE r.timestamp > ((SYSDATE - DATE '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60) - 80000 
  --AND r.id=21 
  AND r.animalid IN ('7','98','3','3') 
  AND r.id = z.id
)
WHERE rnk = 1;

    ID_One        Max      ROUND  TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_DATE           
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------------
         1        500        .01 1640080800 DEC 21,2021 10:00          
         2        232          0 1640128320 DEC 21,2021 23:12          
         3         23          0 1640916720 DEC 31,2021 02:12          
         4         34          0 1640992320 DEC 31,2021 23:12
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b584d6/1), including the inner query on its own so you can see the ranking applied to each row.

Comment: This work on Fiddle I can confirm that with your table. But on my database I'm getting  invalid identifier for vlaue , timestamp and id. When I set an alias it is still not taking them.

Comment: @Ray - well, I was going from the column names you used in the question, so maybe the real names are different? Or are you using this as part of a bigger query?

Comment: I am not using this part of a bigger query. What ends up happpening is I get the row of data listed above but I also get different time stamps as well. that matches my where timestamp rule

Comment: @Ray - I suspect you have more than one `animalid` for a given `id` then. Since you don't refer to it anywhere else you can take that out of the `partition by` clause. I think. [Modified Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/28cdf/1). If it isn't that then you'd need to add some sample data that shows the issue. I'm not sure how that relates to an 'invalid identifier' error though.